# The object is destroyed before being returned

Tags: c++, oop

I can't understand why when one my method return a object, the object will be destroyed.

Post here the class structure and methods.

```
class Var
{
public:
    Var operator += (const Var& var);
private:
    Var _operation(Var* var, VAR_OPERATOR op);
}
```

Method :

```
Var Var::operator += (const Var& var)
{
    Var tmp = this->_operation((Var *)&var,VAR_ADD);
    return tmp;  // here the tmp variable is void
}
Var Var::_operation(Var* var, VAR_OPERATOR op)
{
    Var tmp;
    // operations
    // here the tmp variable has value
    return tmp;
}
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: You didn't implement your copy constructor correctly? By the way, why the cast? Why isn't the _operation argument a const pointer? And if you have a good reason for that, please at least use a `const_cast` to cast away constness instead of a C-style cast.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Yes thx, I had forgotten the copy constructor :S

Comment: It should be const. Operator overloading has come conventions, which come from the intuitive understanding of mathematical operators. If you do a = a + 5, you wouldn't expect 5 to change, would you? So if it changes the right hand side argument, give it a proper function and don't use an operator...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tmp Var exist in its scope... so it exists only inside operator += and _operation. When tmp is out of scope the destructor is called. The right way to do that is:

```
Var& Var::operator += (const Var& var)
{
    _operation(*this, &var, *this, VAR_ADD);
    return *this;
}
void Var::_operation(const Var& lhs, const Var& rhs, Var& res, VAR_OPERATOR op)
{
    res == ...
    // operations
    // here the tmp variable has value
}
```

With the += operator we mean that internal data will changed (in this case that *this += val), so ther's no return type, or we can return *this,  to have situation like:

```
( v += val ) - val2;
```

in `v += val` will be called `operator +=` and thre return is the changed v, now if we define - operator like `friend Val operator - ( const Val& lhs, const Val& rhs )` we can have concatenated expressions.

What you are trying to do is:

```
Var Var::operator + (const Var& var1, const Var& var2)
{
    Var tmp;
    // internal stuff
    return tmp;
}
```

Now this operator can be a friend

```
friend Var operator + (const Var& var1, const Var& var2)
{
    Var tmp;
    // internal stuff
    return tmp;
}
```

This is still wrong because we need to define the copy constructor and the assigment operator! Because it's true that temp will be destroyed but first of that we can call the copy constructor ( or assigment operator ) in a way that we can have a "clone".

All modern C++ compiler allow a thing called RVO (return value optimization) but this is another story.

Comment: I don't want use "this" as result, i need an other variable :S

Comment: so you are choosing the wrong operator, use operator + instead